# Roxygen2 document S4 generic from dependent package

Tags: r, r-s4, roxygen2

General question - how can I use roxygen to document a generic from a dependent package that I have extended, specifically with respect to the `usage` statement.

Let's say I am extending the package `coolPackage`.  Within it, there is a generic called `coolFun` with its own set of methods.

Now, I create a secondary package for a different purpose and extend the S4 `coolFun` with more methods.  Now, normally I can just use the `@rdname` and add multiple functions to the same file.

```
#' @rdname coolFun
#' @export
setMethod('coolFun', signature(x='newClass'),
    function(x){
       #process the class
    }
)
```

However, this results in something like the following:

```
Usage

## S4 method for signature 'newClass'
coolFun(x)
```

This would be fine if I only would use one or two methods, but let's say I have several methods.  The S4 comment would be repeated several times and the call itself is never different.  I understand the importance of denoting S4 methods but would there be a way to collapse this type of behavior so I could just have one document with multiple aliases (for all the new methods) that returns the  simple output instead of cluttered, repeated document?

```
Usage

coolFun(x)
```

This would be easy if the generic was in the second package but I am unaware how I could access this beside writing out the Rd file manually (which is the entire reason to use roxygen).  This may not be possible but it would make the documentation look a lot cleaner, IMHO.